# ASP.NET DataGrid and styling with CSS

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, datagrid

I have never had an issue with putting

```
th
{
    background: #900;
}
```

as a style in a css file and have that apply to the header row of an ASP datagrid.
But for some reason today, I have a grid that is getting output with everything in TBODY
and even the headers are in TD tags. Any ideas?

One thing that is a little different for me is this is bound to a List instead of to a DataTable. Is this a normal behavior? Easy way to fix?

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgEmployees" runat="server">   
</asp:DataGrid>
```

**THE VALUE OF AN IDE**
Okay, so my DataGrid should have been a GridView.
Teaches me to go and type in the  tag by hand again.
Could not figure out what and the heck I had done wrong until I went and looked at an another project of mine.

Comment: can you post the grid declaration from the markup (ascx or aspx)?

Comment: CSS doesn't care at all how you bound your UI objects.  For instance, CSS doesn't play a role if you bind your grid to a custom object, a list, a datatable, etc.  It is simply used for formatting.

Comment: Tim, I just added it. And you were right on the money. I wondering about the Render method getting altered somehow.

Comment: try explicitly binding and using a header template, that may get the th tags your looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS doesn't care how you fill your datagrid.  It could come from a datatable, a reader, a custom Object (employee, product, , etc).  So it is not an issue because you are using a list instead of a datatable.

You will need to post your CSS with your datagrid code.

Here is an excellent link on how to use CSS with a datagrid / gridview:

http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx

Here is one specifically for datagrids:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/cssgrid.aspx

I personally do not use datagrids, should be using grid view or some sort of repeater.

Comment: his question is not the css, but the html render of the grid.  he wants to know why the change in datasource is resulting in different markup being rendered by the control.  specifically, why the headers are not put in a th tag as he is expecting